# why i am not getting stable output?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, for-loop

im trying to self learn java, below code is my try. im not getting output as expected. i have posted my coding below with output.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
abstract class q2Student
{
String name;
int roll_no;
int sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5;
int total;
float grade;
float per;
public abstract void getdata() throws IOException;
//public abstract void show();
public void show()
{
    System.out.println ("Roll No. = "+roll_no);
    System.out.println ("Name = "+name);
    System.out.println ("Marks of 1st Subject = "+sub1);
    System.out.println ("Marks of 2nd Subject = "+sub2);
    System.out.println ("Marks of 3rd Subject = "+sub3);
    System.out.println ("Marks of 4th Subject = "+sub4);
    System.out.println ("Marks of 5th Subject = "+sub5);
    System.out.println ("Total Marks = "+total);
    System.out.println ("Percentage = "+per+"%");
    System.out.println("Grade="+grade);
}


}
class StudDetails extends q2Student{
public void getdata() throws IOException 
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println ("Enter Name of Student");
    name = br.readLine();
    System.out.println ("Enter Roll No. of Student");
    roll_no = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println ("Enter marks out of 100 of 1st subject");
    sub1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(sub1>100){
        System.out.println ("you have entered invalid mark, please check  again and enter a mark out of 100");
        sub1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println ("Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject");
    sub2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(sub2>100){
        System.out.println ("you have entered invalid mark, please check again and enter a mark out of 100");
    sub2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());}
    System.out.println ("Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject");
    sub3 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(sub3>100){
        System.out.println ("you have entered invalid mark, please check again and enter a mark out of 100");
    sub3 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());}
    System.out.println ("Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject");
    sub4 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(sub4>100){
        System.out.println ("you have entered invalid mark, please check again and enter a mark out of 100");
    sub4 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());}
    System.out.println ("Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject");
    sub5 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(sub5>100){
        System.out.println ("you have entered invalid mark, please check again and enter a mark out of 100");
    sub5 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }

}
public void calculate(){
    total=sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5;
    per=(total*100)/500;
    grade=per/10;
    }

    public void result(){

    if(grade>=9){
        System.out.println("Execellent!!passed with distinction");
    }
    else if((grade>=7.5) &&( grade<=8.9)){
        System.out.println("first class!!passed with distinction");
        }
    else if((grade>=6)&&(grade<=7.4)){
        System.out.println("passed!! first class");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("sorry!! you are failed");
    }
    }
}
public class Student extends StudDetails{
static int n;
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Student s=new Student();

    System.out.println ("enter the total no of students");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("the total no of students"+n);
    Student id[]=new Student[n];// array object
    for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++){
        s.getdata();
        s.show();
        s.calculate();
        s.result();
    }

        //in.close();
}
}
```

my output is as follows i gave object array input as 2 and the calculated output was not as i expected

```
enter the total no of students
2
the total no of students2
Enter Name of Student
ram
Enter Roll No. of Student
1
Enter marks out of 100 of 1st subject
89
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
98
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
78
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
76
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
87
Roll No. = 1
Name = ram
Marks of 1st Subject = 89
Marks of 2nd Subject = 98
Marks of 3rd Subject = 78
Marks of 4th Subject = 76    
Marks of 5th Subject = 87
Total Marks = 0           //total im getting 0
Percentage = 0.0%
Grade=0.0           // grade 0 but result states passed with first class
passed!! first class
Enter Name of Student
sur
Enter Roll No. of Student
2
Enter marks out of 100 of 1st subject
65
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
67
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
89
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
86
Enter marks out of 100 of 2nd subject
87
Roll No. = 2
Name = sur
Marks of 1st Subject = 65
Marks of 2nd Subject = 67
Marks of 3rd Subject = 89
Marks of 4th Subject = 86
Marks of 5th Subject = 87
Total Marks = 350        // same method called in second index calculating properly
Percentage = 70.0%
Grade=7.0
passed!! first class
```

Comment: Toooooo much code. Identify more precisely the problem and come back

Comment: Define "not as expected".

Comment: Check the order of the function you are calling   `s.getdata();----s.show();----->s.calculate();`.total is not initialized in `getData()` and you are printing `total` in `show()` giving you default vatlue of int `0`.In the second attempt it worked because `total` was initialized for the first attempt n `calculate()`

Comment: im calling calculate method in a for loop. in the first iteration i get total=0,grade=0 but result is passed, in second iteration the total is calculated total=350, grade= 7.0 result as first class. i want to know y i get 0 in the first iteration of the for loop in main method

Comment: also i tried calling methods like id[i].getdata--id[i].result, in that case i get nullpointer exception in main method. since i created seperate object to call the methods. my order is correct. show mwthod jus displays the entered data

Comment: @singha thank u order of calling the methods were wrong. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++){
    s.getdata();
    s.calculate();
    s.show();
    s.result();
}
```

You need to calculate before you show. I'm not sure though, I didn't read through all of your code that carefully. You should see the help center for [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)